# Verify if copying a folder went ok

Tags: bash

I'm pretty new to bash, but I have the following script that does a simple operation: copying a folder.

In shell, I would type `sudo macaco NewFolder`
and this is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

wwwPATH="/var/www"
bitMotorVERSION="0.0.0"
targetDir="$wwwPATH/$1"

cp -r /var/fw/bitMotor/$bitMotorVERSION/ $targetDir
```

This works fine! Now I want the script to output a little status message, and I 'm having problem with conditions. This is what I got so far:

```
if [ cp -r /var/fw/bitMotor/$bitMotorVERSION/ $targetDir ]
then echo "New Project '$1' Successfully Created!"
else echo "Something wrent wrong"
fi
```

Shell says: `/usr/bin/macaco: line 7: [: too many arguments`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

you should using the return status like this :

```
cp -r /var/fw/bitMotor/$bitMotorVERSION/ $targetDir
if [ $? == 0 ]
    then echo "New Project '$1' Successfully Created!"
else
    echo "Something wrent wrong"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if cp -r "/var/fw/bitMotor/$bitMotorVERSION/" "$targetDir" ;then
  echo ....
fi
```